# Supabase signInWIthPassword is giving me a 502 error

Tags: typescript, authentication, supabase

All auth functions work except `signInWithPassword` using React, TypeScript, and Supabase.

My context: It allows me to `signIn`, create a profile and move on. I am able to `getUser()` during the session when logged in. I can `signOut` as well too.

But when I `signInWithPassword` it tells me

[502 post error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3qgH.png)

and when I put the link into the browser it says:
{"message":"No API key found in request","hint":"No `apikey` request header or url param was found."}

What is happening?

[both errrors after signing in, in supabase logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGTqV.png)

Here is the 'Unhandled server error' error

```
Log ID
2035d09a-e63c-451c-bc66-8386e50ebc42

Log Timestamp (UTC)
2022-11-20T23:10:56.481Z

Log Event Message
{"auth_event":{"action":"login","actor_id":"7888064c-0f26-4e88-9016-c8fe5c16e64e","actor_username":"*********","log_type":"account","traits":{"provider":"email"}},"component":"api","error":"write tcp 127.0.0.1:9999-\u003e127.0.0.1:50512: write: connection reset by peer","level":"error","method":"POST","msg":"Unhandled server error: write tcp 127.0.0.1:9999-\u003e127.0.0.1:50512: write: connection reset by peer","path":"/token","referer":"https://myintent.netlify.app/","remote_addr":"67.167.57.19","time":"2022-11-20T23:10:56Z","timestamp":"2022-11-20T23:10:56Z"}

Log Metadata
[
  {
    "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP": null,
    "CODE_FUNC": null,
    "status": null,
    "_CMDLINE": null,
    "method": null,
    "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP": null,
    "CODE_FILE": null,
    "EXECUTABLE": null,
    "_EXE": null,
    "UNIT": null,
    "level": null,
    "_COMM": null,
    "duration": null,
    "_LINE_BREAK": null,
    "_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP": null,
    "_UID": null,
    "host": "db-sorcthuycbkwhrnjbntk",
    "PRIORITY": null,
    "_CAP_EFFECTIVE": null,
    "_PID": null,
    "INVOCATION_ID": null,
    "_SYSTEMD_UNIT": null,
    "source_type": "journald",
    "SYSLOG_FACILITY": null,
    "request_id": null,
    "CODE_LINE": null,
    "path": null,
    "component": null,
    "project": "sorcthuycbkwhrnjbntk",
    "referer": null,
    "remote_addr": null,
    "_SYSTEMD_SLICE": null,
    "_SYSTEMD_INVOCATION_ID": null,
    "_MACHINE_ID": null,
    "_TRANSPORT": null,
    "_SELINUX_CONTEXT": null,
    "MESSAGE_ID": null,
    "__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP": null,
    "_STREAM_ID": null,
    "_GID": null,
    "_BOOT_ID": null,
    "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER": null
  }
]
```

I tried making sure `process.env` was set correctly, where both the url and anonKeys are stored with REACT_APP prefixes. Nothing changed.

I tried using signInWithOtp by signing in with just an email. When I click the link in the email, it brings me to a page that says:

{
"message":"An invalid response was received from the upstream server"
}

Comment: Could you send an email to support@supabase.com and we will take a look at it!

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same error

`{"message":"No API key found in request","hint":"No apikey request header or url param was found."}`

When I had misconfigured the redirect URL in the Supabase web panel. Under `Authentication > URL Configuration > Site URL`, I had listed `manifund.com`, but it needed to be `https://manifund.com`.